# How to convert dicom file to jpg conversion

Tags: java, image, jpeg, dicom

How we can convert a dicom file(.dcm) to a jpeg image using java?
Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.dcm4che2.tool.dcm2jpg.Dcm2Jpg;
public class MainClass {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
Dcm2Jpg conv = new Dcm2Jpg();
conv.convert(new File("C:\\Users\\lijo.joseph\\Desktop\\Dicom\\IM-0001-0001.dcm"), new File("C:\\Users\\lijo.joseph\\Desktop\\Dicom\\IM-0001-0001.jpg"));
}
}
```

and i am getting the following error while running the project

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException
at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 1 more
```

please help and thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the link [Converting DICOM to JPEG using dcm4che 2](http://samucs.blogspot.in/2008/03/converting-dicom-to-jpeg-using-dcm4che.html)

Following is my code which works perfectly.I have placed it with imports so it might be use-full.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageReader;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;
import org.dcm4che2.imageio.plugins.dcm.DicomImageReadParam;
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGCodec;
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGImageEncoder;

public class Examplke1 {

    static BufferedImage myJpegImage=null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("test5/12840.dcm");
        Iterator<ImageReader> iterator =ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("DICOM");
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            ImageReader imageReader = (ImageReader) iterator.next();
            DicomImageReadParam dicomImageReadParam = (DicomImageReadParam) imageReader.getDefaultReadParam();
            try {
                ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(file);
                imageReader.setInput(iis,false);
                myJpegImage = imageReader.read(0, dicomImageReadParam);
                iis.close();
                if(myJpegImage == null){
                    System.out.println("Could not read image!!");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            File file2 = new File("/test.jpg");
            try {
                OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file2));
                JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(outputStream);
                encoder.encode(myJpegImage);
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Completed");
        }

    }
}
```

**Jars Used to Run it**

1. dcm4che-imageio-2.0.28.jar
2. dcm4che-image-2.0.28.jar
3. jai_imageio-1.1.jar
4. dcm4che-core-2.0.28.jar
5. slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
6. slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar
7. apache-logging-log4j.jar

Hope it helps.

Comment: Already tried and got error while running.
any another way to solve this problem

Comment: i am getting following error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater
 ImageReader cannot be resolved to a type
 ImageIO cannot be resolved
 ImageReader cannot be resolved to a type
 ImageReader cannot be resolved to a type
 ImageInputStream cannot be resolved to a type
 ImageIO cannot be resolved
 JPEGImageEncoder cannot be resolved to a type
 JPEGCodec cannot be resolved
 at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:18)
Please tell the correct import statements. i am using java8

Comment: Change your compilation environment in eclipse if u are using to 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

**This Code is used for Converting Dicom Image to JPG Image**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Dcm2JpgTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try{
            File src = new File("d:\\Test.dcm");
            File dest = new File("d:\\Test.jpg");           
            Dcm2Jpeg dcm2jpg= new Dcm2Jpeg();           
            dcm2jpg.convert(src, dest);         
            System.out.println("Completed");
        } catch(IOException e){ 
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Dcm2Jpeg.java File**

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageReader;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;

import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.cli.GnuParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.HelpFormatter;
import org.apache.commons.cli.OptionBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.cli.Options;
import org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException;
import org.dcm4che2.data.DicomObject;
import org.dcm4che2.imageio.plugins.dcm.DicomImageReadParam;
import org.dcm4che2.io.DicomInputStream;
import org.dcm4che2.util.CloseUtils;

import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGCodec;
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGImageEncoder;


public class Dcm2Jpeg {

    private static final String USAGE =
        "dcm2jpg [Options] <dcmfile> <jpegfile>\n" +
        "or dcm2jpg [Options] <dcmfile>... <outdir>\n" +
        "or dcm2jpg [Options] <indir>... <outdir>";
    private static final String DESCRIPTION = 
        "Convert DICOM image(s) to JPEG(s)\nOptions:";
    private static final String EXAMPLE = null;
    private int frame = 1;
    private float center;
    private float width;
    private String vlutFct;
    private boolean autoWindowing;
    private DicomObject prState;
    private short[] pval2gray;
    private String fileExt = ".jpg";

    private void setFrameNumber(int frame) {
        this.frame = frame;
    }

    private void setWindowCenter(float center) {
        this.center = center;        
    }

    private void setWindowWidth(float width) {
        this.width = width;       
    }

    public final void setVoiLutFunction(String vlutFct) {
        this.vlutFct = vlutFct;
    }    

    private final void setAutoWindowing(boolean autoWindowing) {
        this.autoWindowing = autoWindowing;
    }

    private final void setPresentationState(DicomObject prState) {
        this.prState = prState;        
    }

    private final void setPValue2Gray(short[] pval2gray) {
        this.pval2gray = pval2gray;
    }

    public final void setFileExt(String fileExt) {
        this.fileExt = fileExt;
    }

    public void convert(File src, File dest) throws IOException {
        Iterator<ImageReader> iter = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("DICOM");
        ImageReader reader = iter.next();
        DicomImageReadParam param = 
            (DicomImageReadParam) reader.getDefaultReadParam();
        param.setWindowCenter(center);
        param.setWindowWidth(width);
        param.setVoiLutFunction(vlutFct);
        param.setPresentationState(prState);
        param.setPValue2Gray(pval2gray);
        param.setAutoWindowing(autoWindowing);
        ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(src);
        BufferedImage bi;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            reader.setInput(iis, false);
            bi = reader.read(frame - 1, param);
            if (bi == null) {
                System.out.println("\nError: " + src + " - couldn't read!");
                return;
            }
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dest));
            JPEGImageEncoder enc = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(out);
            enc.encode(bi);
        } finally {
            CloseUtils.safeClose(iis);
            CloseUtils.safeClose(out);
        }
        //System.out.print('.');
    }

    public int mconvert(List<String> args, int optind, File destDir)
            throws IOException {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = optind, n = args.size() - 1; i < n; ++i) {
            File src = new File(args.get(i));
            count += mconvert(src, new File(destDir, src2dest(src)));
        }
        return count;
    }

    private String src2dest(File src) {
        String srcname = src.getName();
        return src.isFile() ? srcname + this.fileExt : srcname;
    }

    public int mconvert(File src, File dest) throws IOException {
        if (!src.exists()) {
            System.err.println("WARNING: No such file or directory: " + src
                    + " - skipped.");                
            return 0;
        }
        if (src.isFile()) {
            try {
                convert(src, dest);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("WARNING: Failed to convert " + src + ":");
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                System.out.print('F');
                return 0;
            }
            System.out.print('.');
            return 1;
        }
        File[] files = src.listFiles();
        if (files.length > 0 && !dest.exists()) {
            dest.mkdirs();
        }
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
            count += mconvert(files[i], new File(dest, src2dest(files[i])));
        }
        return count;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        CommandLine cl = parse(args);
        Dcm2Jpeg dcm2jpg = new Dcm2Jpeg();
        if (cl.hasOption("f")) {
            dcm2jpg.setFrameNumber(
                    parseInt(cl.getOptionValue("f"),
                            "illegal argument of option -f",
                            1, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        }
        if (cl.hasOption("p")) {
            dcm2jpg.setPresentationState(loadDicomObject(
                    new File(cl.getOptionValue("p"))));
        }
        if (cl.hasOption("pv2gray")) {
            dcm2jpg.setPValue2Gray(loadPVal2Gray(
                    new File(cl.getOptionValue("pv2gray"))));
        }        
        if (cl.hasOption("c")) {
            dcm2jpg.setWindowCenter(
                    parseFloat(cl.getOptionValue("c"),
                            "illegal argument of option -c"));
        }
        if (cl.hasOption("w")) {
            dcm2jpg.setWindowWidth(
                    parseFloat(cl.getOptionValue("w"),
                            "illegal argument of option -w"));
        }
        if (cl.hasOption("sigmoid")) {
            dcm2jpg.setVoiLutFunction(DicomImageReadParam.SIGMOID);
        }
        dcm2jpg.setAutoWindowing(!cl.hasOption("noauto"));
        if (cl.hasOption("jpgext")) {
            dcm2jpg.setFileExt(cl.getOptionValue("jpgext"));
        }
        final List<String> argList = cl.getArgList();
        int argc = argList.size();

        File dest = new File(argList.get(argc-1));
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int count = 1;
        if (dest.isDirectory()) {
            count = dcm2jpg.mconvert(argList, 0, dest);
        } else {
            File src = new File(argList.get(0));
            if (argc > 2 || src.isDirectory()) {
                exit("dcm2jpg: when converting several files, "
                        + "last argument must be a directory\n");
            }
            dcm2jpg.convert(src, dest);
        }
        long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("\nconverted " + count + " files in " + (t2 - t1)
                / 1000f + " s.");
    }

    private static DicomObject loadDicomObject(File file) {
        DicomInputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = new DicomInputStream(file);
            return in.readDicomObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            exit(e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException();
        } finally {
            CloseUtils.safeClose(in);
        }
}

private static short[] loadPVal2Gray(File file) {
        BufferedReader r = null;
        try {
            r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(
                    file)));
            short[] pval2gray = new short[256];
            int n = 0;
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                try {
                    int val = Integer.parseInt(line.trim());
                    if (n == pval2gray.length) {
                        if (n == 0x10000) {
                            exit("Number of entries in " + file + " > 2^16");
                        }
                        short[] tmp = pval2gray;
                        pval2gray = new short[n << 1];
                        System.arraycopy(tmp, 0, pval2gray, 0, n);
                    }
                    pval2gray[n++] = (short) val;
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    // ignore lines where Integer.parseInt fails
                }
            }
            if (n != pval2gray.length) {
                exit("Number of entries in " + file + ": " + n
                        + " != 2^[8..16]");
            }
            return pval2gray;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            exit(e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException();
        } finally {
            CloseUtils.safeClose(r);
        }
    }

private static CommandLine parse(String[] args) {
        Options opts = new Options();
        OptionBuilder.withArgName("frame");
        OptionBuilder.hasArg();
        OptionBuilder.withDescription(
                "frame to convert, 1 (= first frame) by default");
        opts.addOption(OptionBuilder.create("f"));
        OptionBuilder.withArgName("prfile");
        OptionBuilder.hasArg();
        OptionBuilder.withDescription(
                "file path of presentation state to apply");
        opts.addOption(OptionBuilder.create("p"));
        OptionBuilder.withArgName("center");
        OptionBuilder.hasArg();
        OptionBuilder.withDescription("Window Center");
        opts.addOption(OptionBuilder.create("c"));
        OptionBuilder.withArgName("width");
        OptionBuilder.hasArg();
        OptionBuilder.withDescription("Window Width");
        opts.addOption(OptionBuilder.create("w"));
        opts.addOption("sigmoid", false,
                "apply sigmoid VOI LUT function with given Window Center/Width");
        opts.addOption("noauto", false,
                "disable auto-windowing for images w/o VOI attributes");
        OptionBuilder.withArgName("file");
        OptionBuilder.hasArg();
        OptionBuilder.withDescription(
                "file path of P-Value to gray value map");
        opts.addOption(OptionBuilder.create("pv2gray"));
        OptionBuilder.withArgName(".xxx");
        OptionBuilder.hasArg();
        OptionBuilder.withDescription(
                "jpeg file extension used with destination directory argument,"
                + " default: '.jpg'.");
        opts.addOption(OptionBuilder.create("jpgext"));
        opts.addOption("h", "help", false, "print this message");
        opts.addOption("V", "version", false,
                "print the version information and exit");
        CommandLine cl = null;
        try {
            cl = new GnuParser().parse(opts, args);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            exit("dcm2jpg: " + e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException("unreachable");
        }
        if (cl.hasOption('V')) {
            Package p = Dcm2Jpeg.class.getPackage();
            System.out.println("dcm2jpg v" + p.getImplementationVersion());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if (cl.hasOption('h') || cl.getArgList().size() < 2) {
            HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
            formatter.printHelp(USAGE, DESCRIPTION, opts, EXAMPLE);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return cl;
    }

private static int parseInt(String s, String errPrompt, int min, int max) {
        try {
            int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
            if (i >= min && i <= max)
                return i;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // parameter is not a valid integer; fall through to exit
        }
        exit(errPrompt);
        throw new RuntimeException();
}

private static float parseFloat(String s, String errPrompt) {
        try {
            return Float.parseFloat(s);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            exit(errPrompt);
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
 }

  private static void exit(String msg) {
        System.err.println(msg);
        System.err.println("Try 'dcm2jpg -h' for more information.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

}
```

Jars Files Used to Run this code

1. dcm4che-core-2.0.23.jar
2. dcm4che-image-2.0.23.jar
3. dcm4che-imageio-2.0.23.jar
4. dcm4che-imageio-rle-2.0.23.jar
5. slf4j-log4j12-1.5.0.jar
6. slf4j-api-1.5.0.jar
7. log4j-1.2.13.jar
8. commons-cli-1.2.jar

If you don't want to use direct **Dcm2Jpg.java** file then you can include below jar file.

**dcm4che-tool-dcm2jpg-2.0.23.jar**

In this jar you can import **org.dcm4che2.tool.dcm2jpg.Dcm2Jpg** this java file