# Java - How to convert a DICOM file to a JPEG2000 file?

Tags: java, dicom, file-conversion, jpeg2000

I need to convert a DICOM file (.dcm) in a jpeg2000 format, someone has a code snippet that perform this operation?

I found in the web only a way for the dcm to jpeg conversion (the first answer to that question: [How to convert dicom file to jpg conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229758/how-to-convert-dicom-file-to-jpg-conversion)), but that doesn't work for me.

Thanks in advice for te help and sorry for my not perfect english.

Answer (score 0):

The best tool I encountered when doing image conversion is ImageMagick (http://www.imagemagick.org/), which supports Dicom as input and JPEG-2000 as output.
I also have used dcm4che for this purpose (it has the advantage to be a purely Java solution), but the JPEG-2000 encoder had a memory leak - so if you have to do it for lots of images, it might be a problem (recent version might be fixed though).