# How To Convert Image .dcm to Graycale in Java

Tags: java, image, image-processing

please i need help
I am trying to convert image .dcm to grayscale in java but i couldn't.
i wan't to know how to read image.dcm in java and convert it to grayscale.

note :: this code is already run for image .jpg,.png

```
package otsuthresholding;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
public class OtsuThresholding {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      try {
         System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
         File input = new File("p.dcm");
         BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input); 

         byte[] data = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
         Mat mat = new Mat(image.getHeight(), image.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
         mat.put(0, 0, data);

         Mat mat1 = new Mat(image.getHeight(),image.getWidth(),CvType.CV_8UC1);
         Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mat1, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

         byte[] data1 = new byte[mat1.rows() * mat1.cols() * (int)(mat1.elemSize())];
         mat1.get(0, 0, data1);
         BufferedImage image1 = new BufferedImage(mat1.cols(),mat1.rows(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
         image1.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, mat1.cols(), mat1.rows(), data1);

         File ouptut = new File("grayscale.dcm");
         ImageIO.write(image1, "dcm", ouptut);

      } catch (IOException e) {
         System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
      }

    }

}
```

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229758/how-to-convert-dicom-file-to-jpg-conversion

Comment: But this Gives me error